# NETBEANS custom code folds

Tags: jquery, netbeans, code-snippets, folding

I am confused why netbeans in version 7 still doesn't support jQuery... specially for code folding...

I have code snippets like this...

```
$('#something').click(function(e)){
   ....
});
```

and of course I'd like my code to be folded, so it would be more readable...

I also tried with cosum fold tags like

```
`//<editor-fold  defaultstate="collapsed" desc="el click">
   .... 
//</editor-fold>`
```

that strangly doesn't work in javascript (only in java I suppose)...

same thing goes for JS singletons...

Please advise, how can I fold some snippets in JS with netbeans

just to be clear, I already activated all options in NB settings for code folding

Comment: this one is already answered here , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539671/netbeans-ide-how-do-i-fold-large-chunks-of-javascript-code-in-netbeans

Comment: if it was I wouldn't post my question. The answer there doesn't actually answer my question...since I specified that it works fine with other chunks and that I already have activated all settings for code folding... I was asking wht NB doesn;t support jquery event chunks and since it doesn't how to DO custom folds in JAVASCRIPT editor

Comment: oh my bad i thought about javascript

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of bug reports:

- [Bug 194774 - Missing support for folding function expressions](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=194774)
- [Bug 196879 - Functions can not be folded when defined as a variable](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=196879)

... so I guess it's just a bug.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans [7.3 Beta 2](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/73/) lets you use those custom fold tags with javascript.  More information [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/javascript_code_folding).