# Code folding in Netbeans for javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, netbeans-7

I just recently started using Netbeans, and i have been working with javascript files, the files are becoming large, and i want the ability to group function in something like this in visual studio, actually code folding.

> **#region**
>   code goes here
>   **#endregion**

After a search i found out that you could use

> **//<editor-fold>
>   </editor-fold>**

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCustomCodeFolds

but this does not work with .js files, as it's treated like a comment.

Please advise, how to add custom code folding in Netbean on javascript files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539671/netbeans-ide-how-do-i-fold-large-chunks-of-javascript-code-in-netbeans - 2nd Google result for "Netbeans Javascript code folding" - does that help?

Comment: thanks for the response @Ian, but this is not what i want, i want an ability to declare collapsible regions, like how the <editor-fold></editor-fold> does. Like i have a lot of function that i just want to group them together, or i have global variables, that i want to create a region Variables, that i can keep collapsed. I don't know if that makes sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently the custom code folding **is not supported on javascript files to the current editor.**

But will soon be implemented in the **new editor** in the official distribution of netbeans,
That allows you to edit your javascript files, with all features currently available in other programming languages.

[New JavaScript Editor](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/new_javascript_editor)

***But if you can not wait more***, then you can download the [Develoment Version of NetBeans](http://bertram-tst.netbeans.org:8080/job/javascript2/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/nbbuild/NetBeans-dev-javascript2-783-on-20121205-full.zip)
Implementing the new editor, without losing your current project settings.

Also you will can create your template code, for make a surround block code. 
 Explained in this [link](http://wiki.netbeans.org/SurroundWithCodeFolding).

And this is the new editor in test

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your response @RTOSkit, will look at the Development Version

Comment: is it available in netbeans 8.0.2?